# Converter SQL para LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

Eu tenho a seguinte tabela

```
CREATE TABLE `ultimaposicaorastreadores` (
`Id` CHAR(36) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Serial` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
`DataGps` DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY USING BTREE (`Id`, `DataGps`),
KEY `serial_idx` USING BTREE (`Serial`),
KEY `datagps_idx` USING BTREE (`DataGps`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
```

Eu preciso fazer esta query

```
SELECT 
lp.Id, 
lp.Serial,
lp.DataGps
FROM   ultimaposicaorastreadores lp
JOIN   (SELECT  Serial,
            MAX(DataGps) AS maxi
    FROM    ultimaposicaorastreadores
    GROUP BY Serial) t1
ON      lp.Serial = t1.Serial
AND     lp.DataGps = t1.maxi;
```

Como faço para converter esta query em LINQ e pegar o ID do registro com a maior DataGPS?

Comment: é entity framework ?

Comment: Sim para Entity Framework 6.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A montagem da query de sql para linq seria traduzida para a forma abaixo.

```
 Contexto.Set<ultimaposicaorastreadores>()
            .Where(x => x.DataGps == Contexto.Set<ultimaposicaorastreadores>().Where(y => y.Serial == x.Serial).Max(y => y.DataGps))
            .ToList();
```